# Printing documents with sidenotes, position:relative and position:absolute

Tags: css

I'm working on a web version of an old document, and it has sidenotes. I've managed to get it looking right in Firefox and Chrome, but there's a problem with printing: the sidenotes are all jammed together at the top of the first page ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/takU8.png)).

I've put up the first section of the old document here, so that you can try it out yourself: http://www.dinkypage.com/117588. As you will see with Print Preview, the paragraph numbers and page numbers work fine (with only one minor problem), it's just the sidenotes that are causing a major problem.

I think the code is fairly easy to understand, but here's the most important snippet of the CSS style:

```
.sidenote, .widenote {
    position: absolute;
    left: 745px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.17em;
    font-size: 12px;}
.sidenote {width: 200px;}
.widenote {width: 400px;}
.sidenote span, .widenote span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px}
```

I've messed with the `position:relative`s and the `position:absolute`s, but I can't get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I've put it up on jsfiddle, but it refuses to increment the page numbers for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/KDzRp/

Comment: Print preview of your example section of document shows sidenotes correctly for me. Chrome 12, OSX 10.6.

Comment: @Brent: Thanks for trying it out, but I thought Chrome doesn't even _have_ print preview. My Chrome is up to date, so am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: If I go to File -> Print... the dialog box gives me a "Preview" button.

Comment: @Brent Here's what my Print menu looks like: http://i.imgur.com/MlTtq.png (it's Chrome 12.0.742.100)

Comment: Difference between Windows and OSX, I suppose. I'm glad @valipour got it figured out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specity "top" for ".sidenote, .widenote", FF and Chrome can determine the Top of your absolutely positioned element by it's appearance in the HTML, but older browsers (and apparently your printer) can not do so.

When using position:absolute always take care of both "hoziontal (left/right)" and "vertical (top/bottom)" position.

If you can not specify the exact top position of your site/wide notes, you need to wrap each page in a position:relative container and give top:0 to your sidenotes.:

```
<div class='page'>
    <p>...</p>
    <aside class='sidenote'>...</aside>
</div>

.page {position:relative;}
.sidenote {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; ...}
```

this way your sidenote will stick to the top of it's own section.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement your suggestion. I added `top: 0px;` to my `.sidenote, .widenote` styling, but it only recreated the collision course originally found only in Firefox's print preview: http://www.dinkypage.com/117593

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm saying, when you don't give it top, FF is intelligent enough to put it in right place, but not the printer. I strongly advise you to go for the last suggestion I made above, use wrapper for each of those sections that have side note (e.g. page) and so on...

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I have one question: given that `.maintext p.normal` is already styled with `position:relative`, then why would it be necessary to have an _additional_ wrapper styled with `position:relative`? Thanks.

Comment: because p.normal is the sibling of sidenote, position:relative on that is redundant. position:absolute element will stick on top of it's position:relative parent, if it's parent wasn't relative, it's grandparent, so on... in case there wan't any relative parent (i.e. your case) it will stick to the top of document.